# obtaining database data for an array of variables

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, foreach

Hi I have created a function whereby the appointment slot times selected using checkboxes on a previous page are added to my database, at the same time the slot times are stored
stored so they can be used further down the page in my mail function.

```
$savedData = array();
foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value)
{       $key = mysql_real_escape_string($key);
        echo($key. "<br>"); // show times selected on previous page
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO appointment(Patient_ID, Appointment_Date, Appointment_Time
            , Practice_ID, Appointment_ID)
            VALUES('$patid','$insertdate','$key','$pracid','$apptype')");   
        //To save the variables for later:
        $savedData[] = $key;
}
```

I now need to use the slot times the user has selected to identify the appointment number which has been autogenerated when they were inserted into my database, the code I have tried to use is as follows:

```
        $insertedapps = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM appointment 
        WHERE Appointment_Date='".$insertdate."' 
        AND Appointment_Time='".$key."'");
        while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($insertedapps))
    {   $appno = $row3['Appointment_No.'];
    }
```

Mail Function:

```
$to = "$pemail";
       $subject = "Booking Confirmation";
       $message = "Hello $pfname 
       This e-mail is to confirm your $appname appointment has been booked for the below times for $insertdate at the the following time(s) below:
       Appointment No:      Appointment Time:
       $appno[0]            $savedData[0]
       $appno[1]            $savedData[1]
       $appno[2]            $savedData[2]
       $appno[3]            $savedData[3]
       The above appointment(s) are booked at the $pracname practice
       Should you wish to alter this appointment please login via our customer login page or contact us on $pracphone";
       $from = "xxxxx@xxxx.xxxx";
       $headers = "From:" . $from;
       mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
       echo "Mail Sent.";
```

The appointment time's print out fine but I do not get the results for the appointment numbers... can someone point me in the right direction with where I am going wrong?

Comment: Not sure if it is the cause of your issue (think I need more details for that) but you appear to be getting one row from the appointment table and then looping through that row. So $appno[3] is probably the practice id rather than the 3rd appointment

Comment: +1 for the dot in the end and for the []. I think PHP has to thrown errors for those two?

Comment: A period at the end of the key works, it's still a string! Try it here: http://codepad.org/Z9sLVBBw But for mysql columns this is true.

Comment: yes sorry guys you are right the field is not Appointment_No. it is Appointment_No 

I have changed this now and I'm getting something back:

Appointment No:  Appointment Time:
3  14:00:00
8  14:15:00
3  14:30:00
14:45:00
the appointment numbers are incorrect for the times shown but 383 is the actual appointment no. of the final inserted appointment @ 14:45:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use $appno[] instead of $appno

Answer (score 1):

`$appno = $row3['Appointment_No.'];`

Will reinitialize the $appno variable every time. So it will never contain 4 values, use `$appno[]` for that.

Also, what is `$row3['Appointment_No.']`? I assume it's an `auto_increment` field, but as was pointed out in the comments, that period `.` cannot be there. Maybe a typo?

Answer (score 0):

as I see you are using double quotes (") and the do not like arrays =D. Put your array variables inside curly brackets like this:

```
{$appno[0]}
```

Have to work =)

Comment: This isn't true. You only need the braces if the subscript is not a literal.

Comment: True sorry about that. Should have tested it first!